# How to change the Path of entitlements.plist

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, deployment

sure there's a simple solution to this, but can't for the life of me find it!

I've just copied an Xcode project from one machine to another.
When I try to compile I get the error:

> CodeSign Error: The entitlements file "Users/Azhar/.../..../...../entitlements.plist" is missing

The path it's showing is to where it was on my other computer, so I'm not surprised it can't find it there, but how can I make Xcode look for the `entitlements.plist` in the new correct folder?

I searched through project settings, but couldn't find anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to file tab-New-NewFile, select code signing in iOS section. U can create a new entitlements.plist file and save that file to the given path.

Answer (score 5):

I know I'm late to answer, just had to fix this myself.
You can change the path to the entitlements file in **Build Settings** -> **Code Signing Entitlements**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Delete the missing file target, you can find it in the projects target should be under the tab build phase. Then drag the missing file to your project files.